# Multipage, dynamic content JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a button for change pages. My problem is, I have a code that i wrote before but it works not that way i would like to.

Here's the code:

```
function loadingPage() {

    $(function () {
        $(".content").load("home.html");
    });

}

function loadingPage_about() {

    $(function () {
        $(".content").load("about.html");
    });

}

button1.onclick = loadingPage;
button2.onclick = loadingPage_about;
```

I want to cut this code using a one function and later change pages in attributes. Something like this:

```
function loadingPage(page) {

    $(function () {
        $(".content").load(page);
    });

}

button1.onclick = loadingPage("home.html");
button2.onclick = loadingPage("about.html");
```

But it doesn't work, page is automaticly loaded after window.onload and buttons doesnt change the content section. Can someone tell me why this code doesnt work? :/

Comment: You really don't need the ready handler (`$( function () {...} );`) in the function. Instead wrap all your jQuery code with it. Also, if you're going to use jQuery, I would recommend using it for your click handlers also, see [`on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thank you, i will see this tommorow !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `loadingPage` is executed immediately and the result is assigned to `button.onclick`:

```
button1.onclick = loadingPage("home.html");
```

To delay the execution, you could e.g. wrap it in a function:

```
button1.onclick = function() {loadingPage("home.html")};
```

Comment: ... Thanks! It works! :)
But maybe you know why actually this is happening ?? Too fast loading ?

Comment: No, it doesn't have anything to do with the loading speed. It's a simple question of syntax -- function name followed by `()` executes a function when the interpreter comes across the line. In the proposed solution, we define an anonymous function that is executed on button click, effectively also delaying the execution of `loadingPage(...)` until then.

Comment: May I suggest having `loadingPage()` return a function that wraps `$( '.content' ).load( page );`. Then you don't have to wrap every call to `loadingPage()`.

Comment: Right! anonymous function! I've tried to do this but i {} all code, didn't know actually that i can do it right there :) 

Is there any options to remove jquery and leave pure js ??

Answer (score 0):

Yup! It works! I wrote a return in main function and I dont need to wrap every call to loadingPage() 
Here's the code:

```
function loadingPage(page) {
    return function () {
        $(function () {
            $(".content").load(page);
        });
    }
}


button1.onclick = loadingPage("home.html");
button2.onclick = loadingPage("about.html");
button3.onclick = loadingPage("info.html");
```

Really thank you guys! You're amazing! :)

Comment: I would remove `$( function () { ... } )` from the function call and wrap it around all of your code if you're not calling it at the end of the document. Something [like this Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/VJ85Cr8Y).

Comment: Thats great :) i'm not calling it, just on buttons :) realy really thank you!

Comment: FWIW, your code above will call `$( function () { ... } )` every time you click a button that has a handler assigned with `loadPage()`.